# View slow ONLY if requested in batches

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, view, query-performance

We have a view which includes a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT
    id AS OrderNo,
    timestamp AS OrderDate,
    email,
    (SELECT TOP (1) reasonId
        FROM dbo.pr_cancel WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE (orderId = dbo.pr_orders.id)
        ORDER BY id DESC) AS OrderReason
FROM dbo.pr_orders WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (pay_canceled IS NULL) AND (pay_error IS NULL)
```

If I use a "select * from view", I get 700k results in a matter of seconds, if I request the results in chunks of 25'000, the second, third, fourth chunks take longer and longer:

```
declare @NumRows int
declare @i int

SET @NumRows = 25000 --return 10 rows at a time
SET @i = 3 --i want the 3rd resultset, 30-40
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER(ORDER BY BestellNr) AS RW,
  dbo.dp_bestellungen.*
FROM dbo.dp_bestellungen ) myAlias
WHERE myAlias.RW BETWEEN (@NumRows * @i) AND ((@NumRows * @i)+ @NumRows)
```

Setting "i" to 5 or 10 makes the query extremely slow (up until 20 minutes).

Removing the sub-query results in fast answer times.

Is there a way to optimize the first query? I cannot change the second query as this is executed by an external system, where I don't have access to.

PS: "dp_bestellungen" refers to the name of the view in the second query.

Comment: Is there a possibility to avoid second query at all and to do all calculations in a single procedure by combing and tweaking two queries? Also in order to optimize the first query, please update the question and provide us with an execution plan

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for your slow query is the fact that you are using `row_number()`.

Your subselect needs to create a row number over **all** rows in your table.

```
SELECT 
  row_number() OVER(ORDER BY BestellNr) AS RW,
  dbo.dp_bestellungen.*
FROM dbo.dp_bestellungen
```

In fact, if you are using SQL Server 2012 or above, you have a quite better solution for this use case.
You can use `OFFSET/FETCH NEXT` to achieve the same behaviour. `OFFSET` defines how many rows should be skipped. `FETCH NEXT` defines how much rows to return, **after** skipping the offset.

You can try the code below:

```
declare @NumRows int
declare @i int

SET @NumRows = 25000 --return 10 rows at a time
SET @i = 3 --i want the 3rd resultset, 30-40
SELECT dbo.dp_bestellungen.*
FROM dbo.dp_bestellungen
ORDER BY BestellNr OFFSET (@i*@NumRows) ROWS FETCH NEXT @NumRows ROWS ONLY;
```

In fact this is quite faster if you have a good index on `BestellNr`, in the best case `BestellNr` is your `CLUSTERED INDEX` for this usecase.

If you can't use `OFFSET/FETCH`, I would try to reduce the load for `ROW_NUMBER` using a selfdefined `OFFSET` using this:

```
declare @NumRows int
declare @i int

SET @NumRows = 25000 --return 10 rows at a time
SET @i = 3 --i want the 3rd resultset, 30-40
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP ((@i+1) * @NumRows)
        row_number() OVER(ORDER BY BestellNr) AS RW,
        dbo.dp_bestellungen.*
    FROM dbo.dp_bestellungen
) myAlias
WHERE myAlias.RW >=  (@NumRows * @i)
```

Comment: Actually using offset/fetch is even slower.than using window function. I would highly suggest you to test the 2 variations first. Window functions use different method of sorting data instead of row by row(using separate windows for each record), which gives them advantage over regular fetch/offset. Also using parameterized sorts(fetch offset), increases a chance of temp spill, due to wrong num of rows estimates. Regardless of all, he asked for advice on the first query (view definition), since he "cannot change the second query".

Comment: I've added some additional code if you won't use `OFFSET/FETCH`. But in fact if the database table beneath is good designed I normally have better results using `OFFSET` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

Your second query has a sort within it:
 `row_number() OVER(ORDER BY BestellNr)` causes the result to be sorted by BestellNr.

To optimize it you can save the whole result (your query without `WHERE myAlias.RW BETWEEN (@NumRows * @i) AND ((@NumRows * @i)+ @NumRows)`) into a temp table and create a PK on RW.

But if the underlying tables change constantly, it's not a solution because the temp table will store only a "snapshot" of your tables included in view at the moment you've cteated a temp table

Answer (score 0):

First

```
select * 
  from ( SELECT id AS OrderNo,
              , timestamp AS OrderDate
              , email
              , reasonId
              , row_number() over (partion by orderId order by id desc) as rn
           FROM dbo.pr_orders WITH (NOLOCK)
           JOIN dbo.pr_cancel WITH (NOLOCK)
             on orderId = dbo.pr_orders.id
            and pay_canceled IS NULL 
            AND pay_error IS NULL
       ) tt 
 where tt.rn = 1
```